# How to add a shadow to a custom UIView created with BezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, bezier

I have created a TicketView using Bezier Paths, which looks like this:

[image: Ticket View]

Now I am trying to add a shadow to it, but I encountered a problem. I also have an image on the left side of this view, and the rounded corners of this ticket view is supposed to work as a mask to it. However, when I apply the mask, the shadow does not work as expected. So far, the only workaround I have found is to add a container view behind the TicketView and apply the shadow to it. Unfortunately, this approach does not make the shadow follow the custom path I created for the TicketView.

Is there any way to apply a shadow that will correctly follow the custom path I created, while still keeping the mask applied?

Here is the code for reference:

```
import UIKit

/// A card view with rounded corners on the left side and a zig-zag shape on the right side
class TicketView: UIView {
    /// The radius used for the left side of this view
    let radius: CGFloat
    /// The zig-zag's width
    let zigZagsWidth: CGFloat
    /// The position within the card's view where the zig-zag starts (1.0 = the end of the view)
    let zigZagStartPosition: CGFloat

    public init(
        radius: CGFloat = 10,
        zigZagsWidth: CGFloat = 5,
        zigZagStartPosition: CGFloat = 1.0,
        frame: CGRect = .zero
    ) {
        self.radius = radius
        self.zigZagsWidth = zigZagsWidth
        self.zigZagStartPosition = zigZagStartPosition
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        layer.shadowPath = (layer.mask as? CAShapeLayer)?.path
    }

    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        // Top-Left
        let topLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY)
        let bottomLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY)

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: topLeftCorner.x, y: topLeftCorner.y))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: topLeftCorner.x + radius, y: topLeftCorner.y + radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: .pi,
                    endAngle: .pi * 1.5,
                    clockwise: true)

        // Zig-Zag
        let zigzagHeight: CGFloat = rect.size.height / (rect.size.height / 7.3)
        let zigzagWidth: CGFloat = zigZagsWidth
        let numberOfSegments = Int(rect.size.height / zigzagHeight) + 1

        for index in 0..<numberOfSegments {
            let inY = CGFloat(index) * zigzagHeight
            let inX = (index % 2 == 0) ? rect.size.width * zigZagStartPosition :
            rect.size.width * zigZagStartPosition - zigzagWidth
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: inX, y: inY))

            let zigZagCurveRadius: CGFloat = 2
            let zigZagCurveCenter = CGPoint(
                x: inX + zigZagCurveRadius,
                y: inY + zigZagCurveRadius
            )
            path.addArc(withCenter: zigZagCurveCenter,
                        radius: zigZagCurveRadius,
                        startAngle: .pi,
                        endAngle: .pi,
                        clockwise: true)
        }

        // Bottom-Left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCorner.x + radius, y: bottomLeftCorner.y))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCorner.x + radius, y: bottomLeftCorner.y - radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: .pi * 1.5,
                    endAngle: .pi,
                    clockwise: true)

        path.close()

        context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        path.fill()

        // Mask
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the layer you are masking is the same layer that you apply the shadow to. This causes the shadow to be masked, i.e. not visible.

Adding a container view works and applying the shadow to the container view works, because now the mask is applied to the view in the container, and the shadow is on the container, so the shadow is not masked away.

You can also add a subview inside `TicketView` - the shadow is applied to `TicketView`, but the mask is applied to the subview.

Or, just add a sublayer. The shadow is applied to `TicketView.layer`, but the mask is applied to the sublayer.

I'm not sure how you observed "this approach does not make the shadow follow the custom path I created for the `TicketView`". If you have set `shadowPath` to the correct path, then it would work. That said, the actual path of the shadows on zig zags like this can be hard to see. To see that this does work, exaggerate the zigzag width, and reduce the shadow radius. You should see that the shadow path follows the zigzag.

[image]

I've used the "apply shadow to `TicketView`, and apply mask to a subview of `TicketView`" approach to create that. Full code (things I've changed are addressed in the comments):

```
class TicketView: UIView {
    let radius: CGFloat
    let zigZagsWidth: CGFloat
    let zigZagStartPosition: CGFloat
    
    // the subview that we are applying a mask to
    let maskedSubview: UIView

    public init(
        radius: CGFloat = 10,
        zigZagsWidth: CGFloat = 50, // exaggerated this
        zigZagStartPosition: CGFloat = 1.0,
        frame: CGRect = .zero
    ) {
        self.radius = radius
        self.zigZagsWidth = zigZagsWidth
        self.zigZagStartPosition = zigZagStartPosition
        
        // create the subview in init
        maskedSubview = UIView()
        maskedSubview.backgroundColor = .white
        
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(maskedSubview)
        maskedSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            maskedSubview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            maskedSubview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            maskedSubview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            maskedSubview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        // set shadow properties except shadowPath here
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowRadius = 1 // made this smaller to see more clearly
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // layoutSubviews is called, so the view bounds might have changed
        // recompute the mask path
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = makeTicketPath().cgPath

        // apply mask to maskedSubview.layer
        maskedSubview.layer.mask = mask

        // apply shadow to self.layer
        layer.shadowPath = mask.path
    }
    
    // I've extracted the path-drawing function:
    private func makeTicketPath() -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let rect = bounds
        let topLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY)
        let bottomLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY)

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: topLeftCorner.x, y: topLeftCorner.y))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: topLeftCorner.x + radius, y: topLeftCorner.y + radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: .pi,
                    endAngle: .pi * 1.5,
                    clockwise: true)

        let zigzagHeight: CGFloat = rect.size.height / (rect.size.height / 7.3)
        let zigzagWidth: CGFloat = zigZagsWidth
        let numberOfSegments = Int(rect.size.height / zigzagHeight) + 1

        for index in 0..<numberOfSegments {
            let inY = CGFloat(index) * zigzagHeight
            let inX = (index % 2 == 0) ? rect.size.width * zigZagStartPosition :
            rect.size.width * zigZagStartPosition - zigzagWidth
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: inX, y: inY))

            let zigZagCurveRadius: CGFloat = 2
            let zigZagCurveCenter = CGPoint(
                x: inX + zigZagCurveRadius,
                y: inY + zigZagCurveRadius
            )
            path.addArc(withCenter: zigZagCurveCenter,
                        radius: zigZagCurveRadius,
                        startAngle: .pi,
                        endAngle: .pi,
                        clockwise: true)
        }

        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCorner.x + radius, y: bottomLeftCorner.y))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCorner.x + radius, y: bottomLeftCorner.y - radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: .pi * 1.5,
                    endAngle: .pi,
                    clockwise: true)

        path.close()
        return path
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Sweeper said (+1), the problem is the mask on the [`layer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622436-layer).

Personally, I would simplify this and just set the base layer of the view to be a `CAShapeLayer`, then you can set its `path` (and other properties) and then set the `shadowPath`, and be done with it:

```swift
class TicketView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAShapeLayer.self }
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { layer as! CAShapeLayer }

    …

    convenience init(radius: CGFloat = 10, zigZagsWidth: CGFloat = 5, zigZagStartPosition: CGFloat = 1) {
        self.init()

        self.radius = radius
        self.zigZagsWidth = zigZagsWidth
        self.zigZagStartPosition = zigZagStartPosition

        backgroundColor = .clear
        shapeLayer.fillColor = .white
        layer.shadowRadius = 2
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let path = customPath().cgPath

        shapeLayer.path = path
        layer.shadowPath = path
    }
}
```

I would make these properties mutable, but just have them trigger a layout if mutated:

```swift
/// The radius used for the left side of this view
var radius: CGFloat = 10 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

/// The zig-zag's width
var zigZagsWidth: CGFloat = 5 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

/// The position within the card's view where the zig-zag starts (1.0 = the end of the view)
var zigZagStartPosition: CGFloat = 1 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
```

Yielding:

[image]

---

Personally, I always make these `@IBDesignable`, so I can add them in Interface Builder and customize the parameters in the UI, rather than programmatically, but that is obviously a matter of personal preference. Regardless, here is my full implementation:

```swift
@IBDesignable
class TicketView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAShapeLayer.self }
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { layer as! CAShapeLayer }

    /// The radius used for the left side of this view
    @IBInspectable var radius: CGFloat = 10 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    /// The zig-zag's width
    @IBInspectable var zigZagsWidth: CGFloat = 5 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    /// The position within the card's view where the zig-zag starts (1.0 = the end of the view)
    @IBInspectable var zigZagStartPosition: CGFloat = 1 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }

    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor? {
        get { shapeLayer.fillColor.flatMap { UIColor(cgColor: $0) } }
        set { shapeLayer.fillColor = newValue?.cgColor }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat {
        get { layer.shadowRadius }
        set { layer.shadowRadius = newValue }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float {
        get { layer.shadowOpacity }
        set { layer.shadowOpacity = newValue }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize {
        get { layer.shadowOffset }
        set { layer.shadowOffset = newValue }
    }

    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? {
        get { layer.shadowColor.flatMap { UIColor(cgColor: $0) } }
        set { layer.shadowColor = newValue?.cgColor }
    }

    convenience init(radius: CGFloat, zigZagsWidth: CGFloat, zigZagStartPosition: CGFloat) {
        self.init()
        self.radius = radius
        self.zigZagsWidth = zigZagsWidth
        self.zigZagStartPosition = zigZagStartPosition
        backgroundColor = .clear
        fillColor = .white
        layer.shadowRadius = 2
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let path = customPath().cgPath

        shapeLayer.path = path
        layer.shadowPath = path
    }

    func customPath() -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        // Top-Left
        let topLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY)
        let bottomLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY)

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: topLeftCorner.x, y: topLeftCorner.y))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: topLeftCorner.x + radius, y: topLeftCorner.y + radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: .pi,
                    endAngle: .pi * 1.5,
                    clockwise: true)

        // Zig-Zag
        let zigzagHeight: CGFloat = bounds.height / (bounds.height / 7.3)
        let zigzagWidth: CGFloat = zigZagsWidth
        let numberOfSegments = Int(bounds.height / zigzagHeight) + 1

        for index in 0..<numberOfSegments {
            let inY = CGFloat(index) * zigzagHeight
            let inX = (index % 2 == 0) ? bounds.width * zigZagStartPosition : bounds.width * zigZagStartPosition - zigzagWidth
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: inX, y: inY))

            let zigZagCurveRadius: CGFloat = 2
            let zigZagCurveCenter = CGPoint(
                x: inX + zigZagCurveRadius,
                y: inY + zigZagCurveRadius
            )
            path.addArc(
                withCenter: zigZagCurveCenter,
                radius: zigZagCurveRadius,
                startAngle: .pi,
                endAngle: .pi,
                clockwise: true
            )
        }

        // Bottom-Left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCorner.x + radius, y: bottomLeftCorner.y))
        path.addArc(
            withCenter: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCorner.x + radius, y: bottomLeftCorner.y - radius),
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: .pi * 1.5,
            endAngle: .pi,
            clockwise: true
        )

        path.close()

        return path
    }
}
```

You may also notice that I replaced all references to the `rect` parameter supplied to the `draw(_:)` method with `bounds`.

The above eliminates the need to implement `draw(_:)` at all, but if you do implement that, never use `rect` for constructing the path. Sometimes, `draw(_:)` can be called where `rect` is *not* the same as the `bounds`. It may only be redrawing part of the view.

Bottom line, in custom `draw(_:)` implementations, use the `rect` to determine *what* needs to be drawn, but never *how* it is drawn.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my question. What I did was create a shadow layer and then added it as a sublayer of the `superview` instead of directly adding it to the view. It worked perfectly. Here is the code:

```
        // Shadow
        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shadowLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shadowLayer.frame = mask.frame

        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 7 / UIScreen.main.scale
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 0, height: 2)

        superview?.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, below: layer)
```

and the complete code for the reference:

```
import UIKit
/// A card view with rounded corners on the left side and a zig-zag shape on the right side
open class TicketView: UIView {
    /// The radius used for the left side of this view
    let radius: CGFloat
    /// The zig-zag's width
    let zigZagsWidth: CGFloat

    public init() {
        self.radius = 10
        self.zigZagsWidth = 5
        super.init()
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    public override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }

        let path = UIBezierPath()

        // Top-Left
        let topLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.minY)
        let bottomLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: bounds.minX, y: bounds.maxY)

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: topLeftCorner.x, y: topLeftCorner.y))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: topLeftCorner.x + radius, y: topLeftCorner.y + radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: .pi,
                    endAngle: .pi * 1.5,
                    clockwise: true)

        // Zig-Zag
        let zigzagHeight: CGFloat = rect.size.height / (rect.size.height / 7.3)
        let zigzagWidth: CGFloat = zigZagsWidth
        let numberOfSegments = Int(rect.size.height / zigzagHeight) + 1

        for index in 0..<numberOfSegments {
            let inY = CGFloat(index) * zigzagHeight
            let inX = (index % 2 == 0) ? rect.size.width :
            rect.size.width - zigzagWidth
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: inX, y: inY))

            let zigZagCurveRadius: CGFloat = 2
            let zigZagCurveCenter = CGPoint(
                x: inX + zigZagCurveRadius,
                y: inY + zigZagCurveRadius
            )
            path.addArc(withCenter: zigZagCurveCenter,
                        radius: zigZagCurveRadius,
                        startAngle: .pi,
                        endAngle: .pi,
                        clockwise: true)
        }

        // Bottom-Left
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCorner.x + radius, y: bottomLeftCorner.y))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: bottomLeftCorner.x + radius, y: bottomLeftCorner.y - radius),
                    radius: radius,
                    startAngle: .pi * 1.5,
                    endAngle: .pi,
                    clockwise: true)

        path.close()

        context.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
        path.fill()

        // Mask
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask

        // Shadow
        let shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shadowLayer.path = path.cgPath
        shadowLayer.frame = mask.frame

        shadowLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.4
        shadowLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shadowLayer.shadowRadius = 7 / UIScreen.main.scale
        shadowLayer.shadowOffset = .init(width: 0, height: 2)

        superview?.layer.insertSublayer(shadowLayer, below: layer)
    }
}
```